# running oracle code on asp.net website causes "driver missing" error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle

running asp.net mvc website that has code that connects to oracle.  Works fine on one machine but on another, I get the following Error:

**System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater.**

Here is the line of code that it breaks on:

```
OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
```

This machine that is failing does have the 10.2 version of the oracle driver installed on the machine. Any suggestions on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the same problem (and possible solutions) on [asp.net](http://forums.asp.net/t/1045815.aspx)